# Broadcast receiver not working correctly when App is Executed

Tags: android

Description of Issue :
I am attempting to develop a simple android app to force connection to a specific open WiFi configuration which is already stored on the phone.

A broadcast receiver is registered to monitor the connection state. If the connection is successful, then i want to print an on screen message.

In the code snippet below, the registered broadcast receiver is ConnectionReceiver(). The toast message is never printed when the application is executed. If i check the phone wifi settings menu, the device is connected to the wifi network.

Any idea why the code never goes into the if (networkInfo.isConnected().... statement in the broadcast receiver.

I executed the following checks :
1. Confirm wifi network device trying to connect to is active. 
2. Confirm device can manually connect to device in settings menu. 
3. Run debugger - add break point on the toast message and confirmed executing is entering if statement but toast message is not displayed. 
4. I also tried to display an activity screen but it also does not display. 
5. Confirmed that the broadcast receiver is registered . 
6. confirmed that manifest file contains the following permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
```

Any idea why the toast message is not displayed in the code snippet below?

```
    package com.agt01.wifitest;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static final String SSID = "vego";
private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_WIFI = 10;
private static final int TIMEOUT = 20;
private ConnectionReceiver connectionReceiver;
private final ScheduledExecutorService worker =
        Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
private ScheduledFuture taskHandler;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    WifiManager wifiManager  = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
        connectToSpecificNetwork();
    } else {
        showWifiDisabledDialog();
    }


}

private void connectToSpecificNetwork() {
    WifiManager wifiManager  = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
    WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
    if (networkInfo.isConnected() && wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "").equals(SSID)) {
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_conect);
        return;
    }
    else {
        List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
        for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration : wifiConfigurations) {
            if (wifiConfiguration.SSID.equals("\"" + SSID + "\"")) {
                connectionReceiver = new ConnectionReceiver();
                IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
                intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
                intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
                intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
               // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                registerReceiver(this.connectionReceiver, intentFilter);
                wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifiConfiguration.networkId, true);
                //Log.i(TAG, "connectToWifi: will enable " + wifiConfiguration.SSID);
                wifiManager.reconnect();
                break;
            }
        }

    }

}


/**
 * Broadcast receiver for connection related events
 */
private class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);


    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        WifiManager wifiManager  = (WifiManager) getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);

        if (networkInfo.isConnected() && wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "").equals(SSID)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_connected);
            toast.show();
        }
    }
}

// User has returned from settings screen. Check if wifi is enabled
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_WIFI && resultCode == 0) {
        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() || wifi.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING) {
            connectToSpecificNetwork();
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    } else {
        finish();
    }
}
/**
 * Ask user to go to settings and enable wifi
 */
private void showWifiDisabledDialog() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setMessage(getString(R.string.wifi_disabled))
            .setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.enable_wifi), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    // open settings screen
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_WIFI);
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.exit_app), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            })
            .show();
}
```

}

Comment: Wait, you're asking "Any idea why the code never goes into the if (networkInfo.isConnected().... statement in the broadcast receiver", but you say later in the summary that you were able to hit a breakpoint inside the `if` statement...

Comment: Apologies for the confusion. Due to the toast message or activity screen not presented when the application is executed, i presume that the code does not step into the if statement. However, when adding a break point inside the if statement, i notice that the code does in fact enter the if statement. Is it possible that the application behaves differently when in debug mode as compared to normal operation?

Answer (score 0):

If the toast message is not displaying even after entering the if statement, generally it could be a problem with context. Try `Toast.makeText(getContext(), text, duration)` or `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration)` etc..

Please check the following code, it works for me perfectly i.e it shows the Hello toast! message. I am connected to wifi before running the app. (To test I changed the if else logic)

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiConfiguration;
import android.net.wifi.WifiInfo;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public static final String SSID = "SD";
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_WIFI = 10;
    private static final int TIMEOUT = 20;
    private ConnectionReceiver connectionReceiver;
    private final ScheduledExecutorService worker =
            Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private ScheduledFuture taskHandler;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        if (wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()) {
            connectToSpecificNetwork();
        } else {
            showWifiDisabledDialog();
        }


    }

    private void connectToSpecificNetwork() {
        WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
        if (!networkInfo.isConnected() && wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "").equals(SSID)) {
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            return;
        } else {
            List<WifiConfiguration> wifiConfigurations = wifiManager.getConfiguredNetworks();
            for (WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration : wifiConfigurations) {
                if (wifiConfiguration.SSID.equals("\"" + SSID + "\"")) {
                    connectionReceiver = new ConnectionReceiver();
                    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
                    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
                    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION);
                    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
                    intentFilter.addAction(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION);
                    // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                    registerReceiver(this.connectionReceiver, intentFilter);
                    wifiManager.enableNetwork(wifiConfiguration.networkId, true);
                    //Log.i(TAG, "connectToWifi: will enable " + wifiConfiguration.SSID);
                    wifiManager.reconnect();
                    break;
                }
            }

        }

    }


    /**
     * Broadcast receiver for connection related events
     */
    private class ConnectionReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);


        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
            NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo();
            CharSequence text = "Hello toast!";
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration);

            if (networkInfo.isConnected() && wifiInfo.getSSID().replace("\"", "").equals(SSID)) {
                setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
                toast.show();
            }
        }
    }

    // User has returned from settings screen. Check if wifi is enabled
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_WIFI && resultCode == 0) {
            WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(WIFI_SERVICE);
            if (wifi.isWifiEnabled() || wifi.getWifiState() == WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING) {
                connectToSpecificNetwork();
            } else {
                finish();
            }
        } else {
            finish();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Ask user to go to settings and enable wifi
     */
    private void showWifiDisabledDialog() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setMessage("wifi disabled")
                .setPositiveButton("enable wifi", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // open settings screen
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIFI_SETTINGS);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_ENABLE_WIFI);
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("exit app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        finish();
                    }
                })
                .show();
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried the following : Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), text, duration); , however the behaviour is still the same. If i move the toast to outside the of the if statement then it is displayed which implies that the ConnectionReceiver is being called and that the context is fine

Comment: In ConnectionReceiver , if i change isConnected() to isAvailable() then the toast message inside the if statement is printed. This is not ideal as the toast message can be displayed even though the device is not connected to the hardcoded wifi access point. Any idea why its not displayed  when isConnected()  is used ?

Comment: @eagleeye, i tried your software. If the device is already connected to the hardcoded wifi AP then everything is fine. If you are connected to another wifi AP, then start the app, that's when you see the issue of the toast message not displaying. The expectation is that it should be displayed when the device connects to the hardcoded wifi AP.

Comment: @seang adding a 'try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }' after wifimanager.reconnect() shows the toast message.

Comment: I updated my code with the try/catch code as requested. The behaviour is as follows, if the device is already connected to the hardcoded AP and the app is started, the toast message is displayed. If the device is connected to some other wifi device and the app is started, the toast message is NOT always always displayed. Is there anything else that i can do to make the behaviour more deterministic?

Comment: For the problematic scenario above, I notice that if i increase the sleep time to 7seconds, the toast message is always displayed. Is there a better way of doing this? I notice that wifi icon on the top of the device screen shows connected almost immediately after opening the application. We should not have to wait 7 seconds for the application to display a connected message after forcing the connection to the hardcoded SSID. Any suggestions?